# Angular Routing: Not able to make redirect

Tags: angular, angular-router

This may be a very common `angular` routing problem but, I cannot seem to make it work. I am not sure whether I understand all the concepts clearly even after going through the angular docs. Here's what I want to achieve and what I have tried:

I have a login application. When the user clicks proceed in the login form, I want the application to redirect to a new page/app. To do this:

1. I first tried adding a `RouterModule` to my `@NgModule imports` list in `app.module.ts` file.

`import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';`

```
// Routes
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", component: InvestigatorLoginComponent},
  {path: 'invdashboard', component: InvDashboardComponent}
];
//...
@NgModule({
// ...
imports: [
// ...
RouterModule.forRoot(
  routes, { enableTracing: true} // <= debugging
),
// ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

2. Added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to `<inv-dashboard>` component:

`app.component.html`

```
<div id='login-app-wrapper'>
  <nav-top></nav-top>
  <investigator-login></investigator-login> 
</div>
```

`inv-dashboard.component.html`

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<p>
  inv-dashboard works!
</p>
```

`inv-dashboard.component.ts`

```
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'inv-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './inv-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inv-dashboard.component.css']
})
export class InvDashboardComponent implements OnInit { // ... }
```

3. Login component:
   `investigator-login.component.html`

   ```
    <form class='inv-login' [formGroup]="invLoginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(invLoginForm.value)">

    <mat-form-field class='inv-login-full-width-input'>

    <input matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="fcUsername" value="" maxlength="30">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class='inv-login-full-width-input'>
    <input matInput placeholder="Password" formControlName="fcPassword" value="" maxlength="25">  
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class='prcd-btn-container'>
       <button mat-button color='primary' type='submit'>Proceed</button>
    </div>
   </form>
   ```

`investigator-login.component.ts`

```
`onSubmit(f: any): void {
    this.authenticator.postContent(f)
      .subscribe(
        this.handleLoginResponse,
        err => { throw new Error('failed'); } 
      );
  }
  handleLoginResponse(res: IResponseSuccess) {
    if(res.status === 200) {
      // success 
      console.log(res.template);
    }
    else {
      console.error('Server error ' + res.status);
    }
  }`
```

When after filling out the form, I click proceed, nothing happens. The stack track shows no redirection. Do I need to add any redirection code to the `proceed` button handler in the form? I am really not sure what else to add.

Thanks

Comment: How are you redirecting? Please share the code of your login component

Comment: @YousefKhan Updated the question with `login.component`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not navigating anywhere on success. Inject `Router` in the `constructor` like:

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

and then navigate on success

```
handleLoginResponse(res: IResponseSuccess) {
    if(res.status === 200) {
      // success 
      console.log(res.template);
      this.router.navigate(['/invdashboard']);
    }
    else {
      console.error('Server error ' + res.status);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I added the `Router` from `@angular/router`. There is an error in the browser console: `this.router is undefined`.

Comment: Did you add `private router: Router` in the constructor?

Comment: Yes I did. In the `investigator-login.component.ts` file: `constructor(
    private invLoginFormBuilder: FormBuilder, private authenticator: AuthService, private router: Router) { this.initForm(); }`

Comment: Not sure why you are facing this. Just make sure that `this` should be the instance of `InvestigatorLoginComponent`.

Comment: I don't see why not. The invocation is in a method, inside the `InvestigatorLoginComponent` class. Plus, typescript should enforce static type check to guard against an `undefined this`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the suggestion from @YousefKhan I tried the solution he posted. It solved my initial problem. Initially, the problem was in how I defined my routes and how I set the `app.component.html` file which, should only host a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` component. I have moved all other templates from `app.component.html` to relevant components and, added the `Routes` in my `app.module.ts` So, after making the changes:

`app.module.ts Router`

```
// Routes
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full"},
  {path: "login", component: InvestigatorLoginComponent},
  {path: "dashboard", component: InvDashboardComponent}
];
```

`app.component.html`

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This resolved the issue of routing and, helped me understand the concept better. For reference, check out this article [on angular routing here.](https://www.sitepoint.com/component-routing-angular-router/)

The other problem I faced, as I mentioned in the comment was that the `this` context inside the `subscribe` handler was not bound to the `InvestigatorLoginComponent instance`. Easy solution would be use an `arrow function`. However, since I wanted to keep my handler separate, I used `bind` to add `this` context to the handler.

`investigator-login.component.ts`

```
onSubmit(f: any): void {
this.authenticator.postContent(f)
  .subscribe(
    this.handleLoginResponse.bind(this),
    err => { throw new Error('failed'); } 
  );

}
```

Hope it helps.